# What is the equivalent of sqlite_master System Table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sqlite

My goal is just to use that SQL command but to traduct it from sqlite to mysql :

`cursor.execute(f"SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='{ctx.guild.id}_counters'")`

In MySQL things are different i saw that on internet so is there an equivalent of `FROM sqlite_master` that means FROM every table of the database in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be something like this:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM information_schema.TABLES t
 WHERE t.TABLE_NAME = 'myname'
```

`information_schema` is an internal MySQL database that has metadata about your databases. The `TABLES` and `COLUMNS` tables are probably of most interest to you.

Comment: It looks like it works Thanks but at the next line when i do ```int(check.fetchone()[0])``` i get this error:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'fetchone'

Comment: That error means that the variable `check` is an integer when that line runs.

Comment: @carpii you can use `fetchone` with MySQL, though `fetchall` would be more typical in most cases.